# Apache, can't link to Home directory, Alias does not work

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, apache-httpd, php, home

I am trying to make a folder in which I can build websites (using php). I have switched from a Windows system where I was using Uniserver (http://www.uniformserver.com/) which is a setup with MySQL, PHP and PHPMyAdmin that works wherever you put it. I am trying to get something like this in Linux (Mint).

I have got the Apache, MySQL and phpymyadmin packages working, however I cannot find a way to have a folder in my home directory that I can use to work from. I have tried making a link to the var/www/html directory, but I get a forbidden message. I understand that I could change permissions on my home directory, but while a learner I know enough to understand that this might be a bad idea. I have tried adding an Alias (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html), but this seems to have no effect. The functionality I need seems pretty basic, so I expect I am missing something, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Otherwise, having anywhere I can work from without having to be logged in as Admin/sudo would be great! :-)

Comment: You may also use `mod_userdir` which allows you to access the users home directory via `http://server/~user` . Refer to `https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html`